# SQL Server Calculated Column using greater than or lesser than

Tags: sql-server

I have this table in sql server i wanted to create a calculated field base on the result of the column that i have, i want the result to display this.
column names are 
Key,Homework,Quiz,Exam,Result,Grade

```
Result=>90 "A+,"Result=>80 "A",Result=>70 "B+",Result=>60 "B"
```

Comment: I have tried to create two Column named( Result and Grade ) the Result is working i use the Column Properties under Computed Column Specification, it is now displaying average but in the Column name(Grade) i don't know how to create formula to calculate the result and display A+,A,B automatically base on the Result

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE  dbo.T
(
    Val INT,
    Chr AS (
                CASE 
                WHEN Val <= 59 THEN  '' 
                WHEN Val BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN 'B' 
                WHEN  Val BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN 'B+'
                WHEN  Val BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN 'A'
                WHEN  Val >= 90 THEN 'A+'               
                END
            )
)
INSERT INTO dbo.T(Val) VALUES (100),(80),(75)
SELECT * FROM dbo.T
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.T
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use concept of derived table like below. I am using `result` column to derive a new column `grade` using `case` statements.

```
create table #tbl(col1 varchar(2), col2 varchar(2), col3 varchar(2), result int)
insert into #tbl(col1,col2,col3,result) values
('A','A','A',10),
('A','A','B',62),
('A','A','C',83),
('A','A','D',94)


SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.result,
case    when a.result < 60 then ''
        when a.result between 60 AND 69 then 'B'
        when a.result between 70 AND 79 then 'B+'
        when a.result between 80 AND 89 then 'A'
        when a.result > 89 then 'A+'
        else NULL
end as grade
FROM
(
Select col1, col2, col3, result
from #tbl
) a

drop table #tbl;
```

Comment: this code run's in query right? how to use this if i want to build it in the table using the COLUMN PROPERTIES under computed column specification is it possible?

Comment: If you want it as computed column, try as suggested by @gbn, in above answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a computed column...

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Grade AS
    CASE 
       WHEN Result < 60 THEN  '' 
       WHEN Result < 70 THEN 'B' 
       WHEN  Result < 80 THEN 'B+'
       WHEN  Result < 90 THEN 'A'
       ELSE 'A+'               
    END
```

If you have fractions (which I've seen at the British Open University) you need to rely on CASE evaluation order and `<`

Using BETWEEN (like other answers) will means a score of 69.5 will not be graded correctly

- [SQL Server Docs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table)
- [A CASE example](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/27/sql-server-computed-column-conditions-case-statement/)

Comment: how to apply this using the Column properties under computed column specification? is it possible?

Comment: This is a computed column example. My first link describes how to use the GUI (I only use SQL not the GUI)

Comment: Bro i'm getting some error cos Result is already computed Column this is the Error":Computed column 'Result' in table 'Score' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.

Comment: You can't use a computed column with another computed column. If you already have a computed column, why do you ask how to do another?

Comment: this is the code on my First computed column Named(Result) ((([Homework]/(100))*(40)+([Quiz]/(100))*(30))+([Exam]/(100))*(30)) is there any other way i could create two column using the Grade and Result?